# How to check if script is running locally or on azure devops

Tags: python, azure-devops

I have couple of scripts that I use on my local machine and on azure devops.

Before running the logic I would like to check which environment I'm using to run it.
I was using a `platform.system()` to check as I have linux on VM and Windows locally. But now I want to migrate to linux on my local machine and it won't work.

Any ideas? Is there any variable that will show me that I'm using azure?

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution based on rickvbosch's answer.

```
import os
if os.getenv("AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR") is None:
    print("Running on a local machine.")
else :
    print("Running on Azure!")
```

Two nice things about this.

1. There are no extra packages required beyond what you would normally have installed. That is, os is standard and no Azure specific package required.
2. It is looking for environment variable normally found in Azure.

Between these two aspects, neither local machines nor Azure instances require any special actions to make it work. Also, in theory, this solution should work on to identify other cloud services by adding elif statements with tests for cloud specific environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables) available. Especially the [Agent variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) would be relevant.

You could use `Agent.MachineName` (The name of the machine on which the agent is installed).
If none of these enable you to determine where you're running the script, you could set an environment variable to an explicit value locally and check for that one in the script.